# How to instantiate custome structure in JNA?

Tags: java, jna

1. This is the header struct in C

```
typedef struct DetectionZone
{
  Zone zone;
  DetectionZoneParam param;
} DetectionZone;

typedef struct DetectionZoneList
{
  DetectionZone* zoneArray;
  int zoneNum;
} DetectionZoneList;
```

2. I used JNAeratorStudio tool generate the following java codes:

```
public class DetectionZoneList extends Structure<DetectionZoneList, DetectionZoneList.ByValue, DetectionZoneList.ByReference> {
  /** C type : DetectionZone* */
  public DetectionZone.ByReference zoneArray;
  public int zoneNum;

  public DetectionZoneList() {
    super();
  }

  protected List<? > getFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList("zoneArray", "zoneNum");
  }

  /* @param zoneArray C type : DetectionZone* */
  public DetectionZoneList(DetectionZone.ByReference zoneArray, int zoneNum) {
    super();
    this.zoneArray = zoneArray;
    this.zoneNum = zoneNum;
  }

  public DetectionZoneList(Pointer peer) {
    super(peer);
  }

  protected ByReference newByReference() { return new ByReference(); }
  protected ByValue newByValue() { return new ByValue(); }
  protected DetectionZoneList newInstance() { 
    return new DetectionZoneList(); 
  }

  public static DetectionZoneList[] newArray(int arrayLength) {
    return Structure.newArray(DetectionZoneList.class, arrayLength);
  }

  public static class ByReference extends DetectionZoneList implements Structure.ByReference {
  }

  public static class ByValue extends DetectionZoneList implements Structure.ByValue {
  }
}
```

3. Here is where I invoke：

```
DetectionZoneList zoneProp = new DetectionZoneList();
zoneProp.zoneNum = 1;
zoneProp.zoneArray = new DetectionZone.ByReference();
```

4. When the `zoneNum` is 1, it's ok, `zoneArray` can be received correctly, but i need multiple zones. When the `zoneNum` must be greater than 1, how can i transmit `zoneArray`?

Comment: What does the API documentation say about the `zoneArray` pointer?  It points to memory elsewhere. Who is responsible for allocating the memory for this array?  Normally the array size goes first so the size can be detected.

Comment: typedef struct DetectionZone
{
    Zone zone;
    DetectionZoneParam param;
} DetectionZone;

Comment: Thank you for your comments,the problem has been solved.

Comment: 1.The Java Structure Code is modified as follows: <br/>`public class DetectionZoneList extends Structure<DetectionZoneList, DetectionZoneList.ByValue, DetectionZoneList.ByReference> {
    public Pointer zoneArray;
    public int zoneNum;
    protected List<?> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("zoneArray", "zoneNum");
    }
    public static class ByReference extends DetectionZoneList implements Structure.ByReference {}
    public static class ByValue extends DetectionZoneList implements Structure.ByValue {}
}`

Comment: 2.Then Convert DetectionZone[] To Pointer:                                                                      `public Pointer Transform(DetectionZone[] zoneArray) {
        Pointer p = new Memory(zoneArray.length * zoneArray[0].size());
        int s = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < zoneArray.length; i++) {
            byte[] byteArray = zoneArray[i].byReference().getPointer().getByteArray(0, zoneArray[i].size());
            for (int j = 0; j < zoneArray[0].size(); j++) {
                p.setMemory(s++, 1, byteArray[j]);
            }
        }
        return p;
    }`

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.  It's impossible to read code in comments.